# GitHub上のコードの挙動確認・コード比較を手早く行いたい

Tags: github

初心者です。
GitHub上のコードを「自分の望む挙動かを確認し、自分のコードとどこが違うのかをdiffしたい」のですが、
実行 & 比較をスピディーに手早く行う方法はないでしょうか？

◆流れ

・git clone (ローカル上にGitHub IDのフォルダを作成)
・サーバー起動 (複数同時起動したいため、ポートを自動で割当て)
・(ブラウザで表示 ← ここは手動でやろうかとも)
・動作確認 (そのコードが望む挙動をしているか)
・diffツールで自分のコードと比較

っといった形をやっています。
アドバイスいただけると助かります。

Comment: 動作確認はもちろん手動で行います

Comment: 「GitHub上のコード」と「自分のコード」との関係がいまいち分かりません。どちらも自分が書いたコードですか？もしくは "GitHub上の" は他人が作成したコードでしょうか？

Comment: 紛らわしかったですね。他の人が書いたコードです

Comment: こちら、もしかして「色んなリポジトリにあるウェブサイトのコードの中から自分の望む挙動をしてるっぽいやつを選んできて、実際にそれがそのような挙動をしていることを確認し、自分のサイトのコードと比較する」ってことをなさろうとしていますか……？

Comment: そうですね。似たような内容ではあるのですが、正確には一緒に勉強している複数のメンバーのコードを比較するには、ローカルに落として動作確認 & コード比較をしたいといった内容ですです。

Answer (score 1):

- ディレクトリ構造やファイル名が同じ
- 行いたのは自分のリポジトリとの差分比較と他の人のソースのチェックアウト

であれば、他の人のリポジトリをリモートリポジトリとして登録することで目的は達成できそうです。

たとえばyukihaneという人のGitHub上のリポジトリ https://github.com/yukihane/a-project.git を `yukihane-repo` という名前で登録

```
git remote add yukihane-repo https://github.com/yukihane/a-project.git
```

し、 取り込

```
git fetch --all
```

めば、

```
git diff yukihane-repo/master
```

で yukihane のコードと差分が見られますし、

```
git checkout yukihane-repo/master
```

でyukihaneのソースがチェックアウトできます(ので動作検証可能です)。
その後、自分のコードに戻したい場合のコマンドは

```
git checkout master
```

となります。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。たしかにファル名が同じであれば、このやり方が使えますね。ただ実際は、ファイルもディレクトリも違ったりするので、別の方法もあれば、嬉しいです

Answer (score 0):

> 自分のコードとどこが違うのかをdiffしたい

この目的のためには、 
私は WinMerge と組み合わせて [git difftool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) をよく使います。

C:\Users[ユーザ名].gitconfig ファイルに
または C:\ProgaramData\git\config ファイルに

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool "winmerge"]
    path = 'C:/Program Files/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe'
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe' -r -u \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

の設定をして

```
git difftool -d [commit] [commit]
```

とやると、コミット間の 差分が 複数のファイル・ディレクトリで 確認できます。

また

```
gitk [commit]...[commit]
```

コマンドを使うと、変更内容がグラフィカルに表示されるので、変更内容の追跡に便利です。